# How do I convince the general population using large monsters is the most efficient means of protecting our compact cities?

Tags: society, government, culture, alternate-worlds, military-defense

**Context**

Monsters are a bit of a problem on this world. Though most pose a marginal threat and are categorized as vermin, others represent a serious risk to major population centers as a consequence of their size, intelligence (or lack thereof), and unconventional capabilities. A loose system is currently in place to provide a quick assessment any threat an individual might represent.

Minimal Concern

- ≥6 ft (3 m)*
- Non-predatory

Major Concern

- <6 ft (1.5 m)*
- Predatory
- Abnormal Capabilities**

Absolute Concern

- 15 - 30 ft (4.6 - 9 m)*

*height
**Abnormal Capabilities include, but are not limited to, projectile acid, electro-magnetic discharge, sonic disorientation.

Minimal to Major Concern are frequently handled by specialized response teams, but monsters that fall under the Absolute Concern category are a significant problem. Frequently they are too large for response teams to manage, but too small to necessitate military intervention.

Static defenses can only dissuade so many monsters before being overrun by the sheer volume of their population and requiring maintenance. The solution to ensuring security during gaps in protection came about unexpectedly and quite conveniently. Nearly every monster is sensitive to telepathic communication, and combining this fact with a small, but stable, population of people expressing psychic potential has led to the pacification - even taming - of potential threats. The result is a local defense that can handle security breaches with minimal damage to infrastructure and at significantly lesser cost than regularly employing military assets.

**The Problem**

Despite sounding completely absurd on paper, in practice the method has proven reliable enough to procure government funding. However, convincing people of the merits in deputizing a creature the size of a bus or larger is difficult. How can approval be acquired and maintained from the general masses?

Comment: Is it substantially different from employing war elephants and guard dogs?

Comment: Somewhat. I am not familiar with the specifics of training animals for combat, but they seem to act as support for their handlers (war elephants keep their riders beyond conventional range and intimidate opponents, guard dogs distract or otherwise occupy their targets). These monsters are doing the heavy lifting while people support them. The most explicit form of support comes from "partners" (psychic personnel with combat training) that mentally synchronize with their assigned partner to impart experience the monster wouldn't otherwise possess.

Answer (score 2):

Propaganda campaign to associate the new tame monsters with cute pets nobly defending people.

Comment: This answer needs some more detail. For instance, the monsters could be dressed up in "uniforms" with insignia and such. Then you have them make visits to parks and schools so that people become familiar with them. Then make movies and Saturday morning kids cartoons about them, etc.

Comment: I like this idea; public exhibitions to familiarize people with the monsters solidifies their role as protectors. However, it's more appropriate to consider once the practice of utilizing them is already established. The problem is getting over the initial acceptance of monster mental manipulation.

Comment: I think the answer is clear and concise, and does not require additional detail or elaboration. A 'propaganda campaign' is well-defined.

Answer (score 2):

Trying to persuade people that your solution is “efficient” is usually a losing proposition. Persuasion needs to speak to emotions and instincts first. To lead your PR campaign, we need to answer two questions:

**1. Who needs to be convinced?**

In every government, there is a number of people who need to be convinced to enact your program. In a pure democracy, it would be 50% + 1 of the population. In an absolute monarchy, it’s one person. In most societies, it’ll be somewhere between those two extremes: maybe you just need to convince a dozen top military brass on a committee, or several hundred professionals in the defense industry, but you need to find the true target population of your message and speak to them.

**2. Why aren’t they behind your plan already?**

If humans made decisions rationally, they’d already be behind your plan, but you need to overcome their objections.

Are they concerned about safety from your tame monsters? Stage demonstrations of the absolute control you have over them. Think of a lion tamer sticking her head in a lion’s jaws - do that with your monsters. Have children pet and ride the tame monsters. They’re family friendly!

Do they have a vested interest in other technologies? Show them how your monsters will also be equipped with the products they manufacture, and sign a contract to prove it. Make sure they’ve got a vested interest in your monsters too.

Finally, nothing will get people in your camp than actually seeing the hero monsters in actions. Get a pilot program going and get some guerilla footage of Mothra saving a bus full of orphans. She’ll be a viral sensation, every city will want their own hero monster mascot!